# RHEL6.6 - pacemaker pcsd GUI disabled

Tags: rhel6, pacemaker

I have a RHEL6.6 OS running a pacemaker cluster (see info below).

After I started the pcsd

```
$ service pcsd status
pcsd (pid  28487) is running...

$ ps -ef | grep 28487
root      6911 28713  0 20:19 pts/1    00:00:00 grep 28487
root     28487     1  0 18:09 pts/0    00:00:01 /usr/bin/ruby -I/usr/lib/pcsd /usr/lib/pcsd/ssl.rb
```

And auth the nodes using the hacluster user.

```
$ pcs cluster auth eastapp1 eastapp2
eastapp1: Already authorized
eastapp2: Already authorized
```

But when I try to go the the pcsd GUI webpage I get this: https://IP_cluster_node:2224/login

PCSD GUI is disabled. Any suggestion on how to enable this?

---

Info about the cluster:

```
$ pcs status
Cluster name: east
Last updated: Wed Jan 13 20:14:29 2016
Last change: Wed Jan 13 19:53:21 2016
Stack: cman
Current DC: eastapp1 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.11-97629de
2 Nodes configured
2 Resources configured


Online: [ eastapp1 eastapp2 ]

Full list of resources:

Resource Group: mastera_sg
    mastera_vip        (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started eastapp1 
    aerver  (ocf::heartbeat:aac):   Started eastapp1 

$ rpm -qa|grep -i pacemaker
pacemaker-cluster-libs-1.1.12-4.el6.x86_64
pacemaker-libs-1.1.12-4.el6.x86_64
pacemaker-1.1.12-4.el6.x86_64
pacemaker-cli-1.1.12-4.el6.x86_64

$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
```

Comment: I see also this error in the pcsd.log

Comment: [2016-01-13 18:19:37] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_accept SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
        /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:174:in `accept'

Answer (score 2):

Because pcsd disable web gui default.

If you need enabled it, you can do it:

stop pcsd service

cd /usr/lib/pcsd

rename file pcsd.rb.disable-gui to pcsd.rb cover old file

and restart pcsd service

pcsd web gui controlled by constants `DISABLE_GUI`

The constants defined at file pcsd.rb#68 (In my version)